# Can I deploy python scripts over a cloud instead of running them on my own computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloud, discord.py

I have a python script that runs a discord bot. The bot only works when the script is running, which means that in order to use it I must constantly be running a python script which is something I don't want to do. I've looked into cloud services to deploy it on and I keep getting talk about event loops and other mumbo jumbo. Is there a safe and easy way to deploy a python script over a cloud of some sort.

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally suggest `Heroku`, I'm using it for running multiple scripts for free. You can use `scheduler addon` for scheduling scripts to run at particular time as well. Please refer to `heroku` documentation & get started!

Comment: Thanks this worked an absolute treat for me. I haven't had the best look at the docs but I was wondering if there was a way to stop and start the script from a Heroku command line?

Comment: Yes. It is similar as of running python script. Run `heroku run python your_script.py` from CMD or you can get the heruku bash terminal first and run script by `heroku run bash`[this will open heroku terminal] then run `python your_script.py`. To stop the script, you can press `CTRL + C`. Make sure you are at same directory where your script is there.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be a VPS service like [VULTR](https://www.vultr.com/) which I personally use and it costs about $5 a month but you get 1000gb of bandwidth which is nice.

If you're looking for something free then [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) should be your choice as it's easy to get started although I think there's a restriction where you can only make some amount of requests per month.